# Календарь jQuery с ограничением до сегодняшнего дня

Tags: jquery, календарь

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите календарь jQuery, в котором нельзя было бы указать дату старше сегодняшнего дня. А минимальную, с 1900 года.

Сам найти нужный не могу. Уже сколько ссылок перепробовал, и ничего не выходит.

Спасибо!

Comment: И [minDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate) не забудьте в 1900 установить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте  в стандартном календаре [JQueryUI datepicker](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate) указать maxDate.

Comment: Спасибо большое! То что надо.